# How to order MySQL results by another table's count?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table containing game entries:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| game_id | title  | description | entry_time          |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | Game 1 | Descript... | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 2       | Game 2 | Descript... | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

And another containing game play history:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| game_id | user_id     | entry_time          |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1       | 0da89sadf89 | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1       | f8jsf89vjs9 | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2       | f8jsf89vjs9 | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to select results from the first table, based on game popularity.

```
SELECT games.game_id, games.title, games.description
  FROM `games`
  JOIN foo_db.game_plays game_plays
    ON game_plays.game_id LIKE games.game_id
  WHERE games.title LIKE "%game%"
  ORDER BY COUNT(game_plays.game_id) DESC, games.entry_time DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

But for some reason, only one result is returned ("Game 1").

When I remove `JOIN`, and just order the results by `entry_time`, both results are returned as expected.

Comment: `GROUP BY` missing. `JOIN` is not handled properly too.

Comment: Could you expand on `JOIN` (I added `GROUP BY` and it's working know).

Comment: game_plays.game_id LIKE games.game_id?  Why not  game_plays.game_id = games.game_id

Comment: @Jens I guess because I didn't research the differences properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this query. Could you please try this.

```
SELECT a.game_id, a.title, a.description, b.total
  from games a
  JOIN (SELECT game_id, count(user_id) as total from
           game_play group by game_id) b
  ON a.game_id = b.game_id
  AND a.title LIKE '%Game%'
  ORDER BY b.total DESC, a.entry time DESC
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Click Here]

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Because MySQL is sometimes really slow when mixing `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`, a corelated subquery might be a good alternative:

```sql
SELECT games.game_id, games.title, games.description
FROM `games`
WHERE games.title LIKE "%game%"
ORDER BY (
    SELECT COUNT(game_plays.game_id)
    FROM foo_db.game_plays
    WHERE game_plays.game_id = games.game_id
) DESC, games.entry_time DESC
LIMIT 10
```